# How Can I Implement An Accumulator in a ProgressBar in Visual Basic?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

So I have a progress bar in the right hand corner of the form
on the top of the form, there is a clue in a label and objects scattered all over the form which are enclosed in the 
forms of buttons. The user only has 3 tries to guess what the object is based on the clue. Now I am trying to use a progress bar to keep track of the guess? I am so confused not sure where to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Maximum` property of the ProgressBar to 3.  Now create a **counter** variable that gets incremented when the user clicks on a button that is incorrect.  Then simply set the `Value` property of the ProgressBar to the value of your counter variable.

Here's a simplified example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Counter As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = 3
        For Each Btn As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
            AddHandler Btn.Click, AddressOf Btn_Click
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If True Then ' <-- change to determine if click is incorrect
            Counter = Counter + 1
            ProgressBar1.Value = Counter
            If Counter = 3 Then
                MessageBox.Show("You Failed!")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```